Recreate the functions environment from the l3doc class file
I am reviewing the l3doc.cls class file and I was very interested in recreating the functions margin environment as shown in the diagram below:

Note that I am only interested in the section that says New and Updated with the correct date and format.
So the manner of usage would be to add the tag New or Updated along with the date to changes I make to Mathematics syllabus.
I have managed to extract part of the code that defines the functions environment but I am struggling in removing all other extra features that exist in the l3doc.cls class. I know I can do this with a much simpler command, say \marginpar but I love the robust aspect of it as defined below.
Any assistance in recreating an environment, say newsyllabusline and updatedsyllabusline would be appreciated. The part where it must adhere to the date format is nice too.
Here is what I have extracted so far that are relevant:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l__codedoc_functions_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l__codedoc_descr_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l__codedoc_syntax_coffin

\box_new:N \g__codedoc_syntax_box

\dim_new:N \l__codedoc_trial_width_dim

\tl_new:N \l__codedoc_date_added_tl
\tl_new:N \l__codedoc_date_updated_tl
%-------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__codedoc_date_set:Nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nn #1 {#2}
    \regex_replace_once:nnNF
      { \A(\d\d\d\d)[-/](\d\d?)[-/](\d\d?)\Z } { \1-\2-\3 } #1
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { l3doc } { date-format } {#2}
        \tl_set:Nn #1 { 1970-01-01 }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__codedoc_date_set_past:Nn #1#2
  {
    \__codedoc_date_set:Nn #1 {#2}
    \exp_args:No \__codedoc_date_compare:nNnT
      {#1} > { \c_sys_year_int - \c_sys_month_int - \c_sys_day_int }
      {
        \msg_error:nnee { l3doc } { future-date }
          { \tl_to_str:N \l__codedoc_macro_argument_tl }
          {#1}
      }
  }
%-------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new:Npn \__codedoc_typeset_dates:
  {
    \bool_lazy_and:nnF
      { \tl_if_empty_p:N \l__codedoc_date_added_tl }
      { \tl_if_empty_p:N \l__codedoc_date_updated_tl }
      { \midrule }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__codedoc_date_added_tl
      {
        \multicolumn { 2 } { @{} r @{} }
          { \scriptsize New: \, \l__codedoc_date_added_tl } \\
      }

    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__codedoc_date_updated_tl
      {
        \multicolumn { 2 } { @{} r @{} }
          { \scriptsize Updated: \, \l__codedoc_date_updated_tl } \\
      }
  }
 
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__codedoc_function_typeset:
  {
    \dim_zero:N \l__codedoc_trial_width_dim
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l__codedoc_functions_coffin { \__codedoc_typeset_functions: }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__codedoc_trial_width_dim
      { \box_wd:N \l__codedoc_functions_coffin }
    \bool_set:Nn \l__codedoc_long_name_bool
      { \dim_compare_p:nNn \l__codedoc_trial_width_dim > \marginparwidth }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__codedoc_function_descr_start:w
  {
    \vcoffin_set:Nnw \l__codedoc_descr_coffin { \textwidth }
      \noindent \ignorespaces
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__codedoc_function_descr_stop:
  { \vcoffin_set_end: }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__codedoc_function_assemble:
  {
    \hcoffin_set:Nn  \l__codedoc_syntax_coffin
      { \box_use_drop:N \g__codedoc_syntax_box }
    \bool_if:NTF \l__codedoc_long_name_bool
      {
        \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn
          \l__codedoc_output_coffin {hc} {vc}
          \l__codedoc_syntax_coffin {l} {T}
          {0pt} {0pt}
        \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn
          \l__codedoc_output_coffin {l} {t}
          \l__codedoc_functions_coffin  {r} {t}
          {-\marginparsep} {0pt}
        \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn
          \l__codedoc_output_coffin {l} {b}
          \l__codedoc_descr_coffin  {l} {t}
          {0.75\marginparwidth + \marginparsep} {-\medskipamount}
        \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l__codedoc_output_coffin
          {\l__codedoc_descr_coffin-l} {\l__codedoc_descr_coffin-t}
          {0pt} {0pt}
      }
      {
        \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn
          \l__codedoc_output_coffin {hc} {vc}
          \l__codedoc_syntax_coffin {l} {t}
          {0pt} {0pt}
        \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn
          \l__codedoc_output_coffin {l} {b}
          \l__codedoc_descr_coffin  {l} {t}
          {0pt} {-\medskipamount}
        \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn
          \l__codedoc_output_coffin {l} {t}
          \l__codedoc_functions_coffin  {r} {t}
          {-\marginparsep} {0pt}
        \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l__codedoc_output_coffin
          {\l__codedoc_syntax_coffin-l} {\l__codedoc_syntax_coffin-T}
          {0pt} {0pt}
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__codedoc_typeset_functions:
  {
    \small\ttfamily
    \__codedoc_target:
    \Hy@MakeCurrentHref { HD. \int_use:N \c@HD@hypercount }
    \begin{tabular} [t] { @{} l @{} >{\hspace{\tabcolsep}} r @{} }
      \toprule
      \__codedoc_function_extra_labels:
      \__codedoc_names_typeset:
      \__codedoc_typeset_dates:
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \normalfont\normalsize
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
sample
\end{document}

The l3doc.cls can be found in the source file l3kernel.tds.zip under l3kernel.tds.zip\tex\latex\l3kernel
The purpose of the question is to expand my knowledge in l3 implementaton with robust structures.

you don't need to go to a source zip, l3doc.cls will be installed in your tex system something like /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3doc.cls  it would help if you clarified more your intended use as from your description it sounds like you just need a simple \marginpar but the code you show almost all the complication is aligning a multi-line syntax block and handling dates in yyy/mm/dd and yyy-mm-dd formats, none of which I suspect you need.

If you only need new and updated see tcolorbox documentation. Also nothing stops you from using documentclass{l3doc} instead of article. l3 is based on article though. Just give some more details in your question.

@DavidCarlisle thanks for the comment. I do recognize a simple \marginpar would do but I just fell in love about how the function environment was defined and wanted to see a use case of only the New and Updated feature since I do not need the rest of the aspects like code or command declarations.

@yannisl thanks for hinting me to the tcolorbox package. I am aware of such package but I wanted an l3 implementation that gives me New or Updated with date formatting for newly added lines or updated ones. I am creating a style file for a Mathematics syllabus I am writing.

I am not too sure I understand you correctly, do you need it when generating the style file or to me used later when typesetting the Mathematics syllabus. The l3 code is tightly coupled with a lot of other functions. The function environment, needs the syntax environment, as it stacks these functions using coffins. Then these are coupled to the indexing commands, and the hyperref  functions etc. I forked the l3doc sometime back and took a lot of effort to make it do what I wanted.
